# How to compile a third party driver into the kernel?

Tags: drivers, kernel, compiling

I am using Linux Mint 17.2 on Toshiba c640. As my LAN driver is no more functional, I am using a USB to LAN converter which was provided with some driver installation files. Every time i want to use the device I have to install the drivers manually by running the given commands. So I am requesting u guys if u could help me to make it automatically load them after every rebooting. For that purpose manufacturer have given some instructions but since I am not a pro techie I couldn't do it myself. I am providing the details of files. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

These are the files:

[image]

Contents are

`Readme.txt`:

```
Note:
    1. Please run as root
    2. Supported linux kernel range from 2.6.x to 3.8.x
    3. CH9x00 module depends on mii and usbnet modules
    4. If you want complied this module in kernel, refer to followed
        a. # cp ch9x00.c ~/2.6.25/driver/net/usb/
        b. # cd ~/2.6.25/driver/net/usb/
        c. modified Makefile and Kconfig for ch9x00.c

Install:
    # make
    # make load

Uninstall:
    # make unload
```

`Makefile`:

```
    # This makefile for CH9X00 network adaptor

# Makefile for linux 2.6.x - 3.8.x

ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE), )
#call from kernel build system
obj-m := ch9x00.o
else
KERNELDIR := /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
PWD := $(shell pwd)

modules:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD)

load:
    modprobe mii
    modprobe usbnet
    insmod ch9x00.ko

unload:
    rmmod ch9x00

clean:
    rm -rf *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.mod.c .tmp_versions modules.* Module*
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

From one newbie to another; if I understand you need to install the drivers (english is not my native language), if so, in terminal do the following:

```
cd /path-to-your-folder/containing-the-drivers/
```

by your screenshot would be:

```
cd /home/maddys/Desktop/linux\ (copy)/
```

once there type:

```
sudo make
```

Then some libraries will be locally created, next type:

```
sudo make load
```

This will install the driver, and that's all.